# Unit Testing $q with location listener (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a controller that does two things:

1)  executes a function when promise is fulfilled ($q.then)

2)  executes a function when `'onLocationChangedStart'` event is fired

In my unit test, I want to test the functionality of (1).  I do this by executing `$RootScope.$apply()` to trigger the promise resolution.   Unfortunately, it turns out that `$rootScope.$apply()` also emits an `'onLocationChangedStart'` event where the url = `http://server/` (this is within the angular code).

Obviously that's an issue since it will fire (2) even though that is not what I wanted for this particular unit test.

Is there any simple way around this that does not involve modifying original code just to get the unit test to run?   (for example, I *could* put function (2) on `$scope` and then mock it to null prior to running the test.  But that seems hackish)

**Updated with scrubbed code sample:**

```
angular.module('myMod')

.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $log, myService, $location) {

     myService.doSomething()
           .then(function () {
               //does something

           })

       })


    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);

    function routeChange(event, currentUrl, nextUrl) {
           //does something
    };

})

//Jasmine unit test
describe('test', function () {
    var $scope,
         ctrl,
         $rootScope;


    beforeEach(function () {

        module("myMod");
          module("myServiceMock");


        inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _myService_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();


            ctrl = $controller('ctrl', {
                $scope: $scope

            });


        });
    });


    it("Should set startup values appropriately", inject(function () {

        //doing this triggers both the myService promise AND the location event listener
        $rootScope.$apply();



}));
```

Comment: you should either mock the event triggering function or the promise resolution function. that's the normal way to go for unit tests

Comment: @Alp - but doesn't that mean I would have to put one of the functions on $scope?  Which would mean making something available to the view that it does not need.  If true, that's why I consider it "hackish" and didn't want to go down that path.

Comment: not really, you need to monkey patch the appropriate functionality. i don't know how your application looks, but it's probably something like mocking the $http or $resource service. i cannot give further advice without seeing the code

Comment: @Alp - OK added code.   One simple thing I could do I guess is put the listener detach function on $scope rather than the full function itself.   Something like:    $scope.onRouteChangeOff = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);    Then call onRouteChangeOff prior to invoking $apply in my unit tests.   Still feels wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$digest()` instead of `$scope.$apply()`. `$digest()` will only execute watched expressions on the current scope, whereas `$apply()` runs `$rootScope.$digest()`:

```
it("Should set startup values appropriately", function() {
   $scope.$digest();
   // promise resolved
   // onLocationChangedStart event not fired
});
```

Comment: Nice!  Bonus for adding a clear explanation of _why_ it works :)